# Using a incrementation of a variable in a while

Tags: c

I don't have the right to use more than 25 lines for a function.
One of my function has just 26 lines so I want to simplified it.

```
char *name(int big, int small, int nb, char *tab)
{
    while (big < nb)
    {
        small = 1;
        while (small < nb)
        {
            ....
            printf("here are the other lines\n");
            ....
            small++;
         }
    big++;
    }
    return (tab);
}
```

big and small are initialize at 1.
How could I include the small++ and big++ in the while condition?

I tried `while (big++ && big < nb)`, it doesn't work why ?
The only way I just found is `while ((big = big + 1) && big < nb)`

Does anyone can explain why the first way doesn't work and if you have another solution ?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe `while (big++ < nb)`?

Comment: What's the point of receiving `small` as a parameter if you just change its value every iteration of the outer loop?

Comment: The inner loop could easily be replaced by a `for` loop: `for (int small = 1; small < nb; ++small) { ... }`

Comment: Also `while (small+ < nb)`.

Comment: And BTW, white-spaces are completely ignored by the compiler. You can dispense with newlines completely and just write the function in a single long line.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I don't have the right to use for !

Comment: @StoryTeller : it's because I need to reduce the number of line, and actually other functions use also the int.
And about white-space I have a norme to respect (as the 25 lines maximum)

Comment: Your function prototype is wrong, you have `small` twice, the second time without a type.

Comment: @f42 if you don't have the right to use `for` (stupid requirement BTW), you should mention this in your question.

Comment: @MichaelWalz you're right, I though it was enought asking how to do it in a while

Comment: There are problems best solved with for loops (counting to a specific value) and problems that are best solved with while (doing something until a certain condition is met), both can be used for both problems but, the usecase should be dependent on the problem and not on some arbitrary restriction. Teaching people to programm is more than that....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want this (two lines less than your solution):

```
char *name(int big, int nb, char *tab)
{
    while (big++ < nb)
    {
        int small = 1;
        while (small++ < nb)
        {
            ....
            printf("here are the other lines\n");
            ....
        }
    }
    return tab;
}
```

Disclaimer: this is untested code.

`while (big++ && big < nb)` doesn't work, because it is simply not the same thing as:

```
while (big < nb)
{
  ...
  big++;
}
```

With `while (big++ && big < nb)` you increment `big` *prior* to the test. In the original code `big` is incremented *after* the test.

BTW: `while ((big = big + 1) && big < nb)` is the same thing as `while (big++ < nb)`.

Comment: For the incrementation before or after, I change the value to 0 instead of 1 to try, but my program didn't enter to the while.
else, your code answer my question, I didn''t think about that way !
thank you